# Problem with Pulling Event Entries

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

The following code is throwing an error for me.

```
{% set eventEntries = craft.entries.find({
    section: 'events',
    event_startDateTime: '<= {{ now }}',
    limit: '4'
}) %}

{% for entry in eventEntries %}
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object

What I'm trying to do is pull 4 events where a date field (event_startDateTime) is before the current time.  My suspicion is that the {{ now }} variable isn't parsing inside the single quotes, but I'm not entirely sure.  Can anyone correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Twig, you'll never need to double up on your curly brackets.  I.E.

```
{{ {{ }} }}
```

or

```
{% {{ }} %}
```

Change this (which is already inside of `{% %}`:

```
event_startDateTime: '<= {{ now }}',
```

To use string concatenation like this:

```
event_startDateTime: '<= ' ~ now,
```

And you should be set.